# Table pagination with labelDisplayedRows - margin-bottom?

Tags: css, reactjs, dom, material-ui, pagination

If I use a labelDisplayRows function with a string of text (no div or p) then I get a bottom margin I don't want under the text (so attribute holding the text and its bottom margin isn't verically centered with the paging arrows). How do I fix this in the most correct way for Material UI?

If I add 'component=div' to the TablePagination, the entire TablePagination loses its current styling. If I wrap the labelDisplaysRows function with a p or div, I get other problems I have to fix. I'm looking for a fix that is more in line with what Material UI would generally want as opposeded to any CSS fix.

I'm not using a table with this component. The pager is paging through a large data set but not kept in a material ui table.

```
export default function Pager2(props) {
  const pagesInResultSet = Math.round(props.resultCount / props.resultsPerPage);
  const moreThanOnePage = pagesInResultSet > 1;

  if (!moreThanOnePage) return <></>;

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    props.setCurrentPage(newPage + 1);
  };
  return (
    <Container className="pager" align="center">
    <TablePagination
      className="pager-label"
      align="center"
      count={props.resultCount}
      page={props.currentPage - 1} // zero-based control from material ui
      onPageChange={handleChangePage}
      rowsPerPage={props.resultsPerPage}
      rowsPerPageOptions={[props.resultsPerPage]} // don't display b/c there is a single value
      showFirstButton={true}
      showLastButton={true}
      labelDisplayedRows={({ from, to, count }) =>
        `${props.currentPage} of ${Math.round(
          props.resultCount / props.resultsPerPage
        )} pages`
      }
    />
    </Container>
  );
}
```